# AngularJS Filter selection by variable

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope variable (btw. controllerAs = vm) and want to filter based on the value of the scope variable. e.g.

where vm.myfilter is set in my controller as either 'filtera' or 'filterb'.  I have implemented both custom filters.

```
<span data-ng-bind-html="vm.myvalue | vm.myfilter"></span>
```

I have tried 
and various options, but filters do not seem to handle expressions.

Comment: Need some more details. Could you please post controller code as well ?

Comment: Please post your filter implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was easy - I asked this when I knew a lot less about angular. I was  wanting to use a different filter based on some condition.

So the answer is..

```
<span data-ng-bind-html="vm.myvalue | {{ vm.myfilter }}"></span>
```

But if you want to be even more adventurous you can do this.

In template..

```
<span data-ng-bind-html="vm.myvalue | {{vm.chooseFilter()}}"></span>
```

In controller..

```
chooseFilter() {
  if (myCondition) {
    return 'dateToNow';     
  } else {
    if (myCondition2) {
      return 'dateTime';
    } else {
      return 'dateToNow;;
    }
  }
}
```

When defining module...

```
import moment from "moment";

angular.module('myModule', [])
  .filter('dateToNow', () => date => moment(date).fromNow())
  .filter('dateTime', () => date => moment(date).format('LLL'));
```

Where filtera is dateToNow and filterb is dateTime

I appreciate there are other techniques, such as making the filter itself decide or even chaining filters and allowing each one to decide.

Answer (score 0):

can you try removing vm for the filter and try?

```
<span data-ng-bind-html="vm.myvalue | myfilter"></span>
```

please share filters code if it wont work

Comment: This doesn't allow to selectively choose a different filter.